# How to monitor a directory for changes across reboots?

Tags: files, scripting, inotify, logstash

I'm searching for a tool that will allow me to run a program for every change in a directory, but is guaranteed to run exactly once per change even across system reboots. For the purposes of this question, (inode, mtime, size) is sufficient to detect a "change". Does something like this already exist?

Things that are insufficient:

- [stat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat). I could hand-roll a script that stored a stat database, and run it from cron, but ideally I'd like something that tied into inotify while it was running to instantly detect changes.
- [inotifywait](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait). Obviously, my inotify watches would be destroyed on reboot. I'm looking for something that could (for example) be run by cron every 5 minutes and still detect every change only once.
- [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html). I know that logstash can monitor a directory of files in the manner that I'm looking for, but it's designed to handle log files. It may be possible to hack logstash to do what I want, but I couldn't figure out how.

Does anything like this exist, or am I out of luck?

Comment: Are those changes expected to come from some specific source, like some application, or users over some network protocol (like NFS or Samba)? If so, how about fixing the service start-up order so that your inotify watch is started at reboot *before* the application or the sharing protocol is started, effectively guaranteeing that no changes can happen before your watch is in place?

Comment: “Guaranteed to run exactly once” isn't a useful guarantee. If the system crashes immediately after the program has started running but before it's had time to do anything, this is compliant with your requirement, but the effect is indistinguishable from a crash happening immediately after the triggering change but before running the program. What do you want to do in this case? The usual solution is to accept the occasional double running.

Comment: @telcoM that's a great workaround, but when my service crashes I'm going to get missed notifications, which I don't like.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' fair, and I'm willing to tolerate "the occasional double run". But I can't accept something that, for example, starts a watch and then just outputs a full directory listing "in case there were any updates before the last program exit".